# Unfortunately [app name] has stopped

Tags: android

**My Application name is timepass
The below file is MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.timepass;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView Display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
counter=0;
add= (Button) findViewById(R.id.badd);
sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bsub);
Display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
counter++;
Display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

    }
});

sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
counter--;
Display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
}
});


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

}
```

The below file is activity_main.xml which is realted to the above file  MainActivity.java

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:background="@drawable/pic_two">"

<Button
android:id="@+id/badd"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvdisplay"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bsub"
android:text="@string/but1"
android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvdisplay"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvdisplay"
android:text="@string/hello_world"
android:textSize="@dimen/asa" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvdisplay"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/str1"
android:textColor="@layout/activity_main"
android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/bsub"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvdisplay"
android:layout_below="@+id/tvdisplay"
android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
android:text="@string/but2"
android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Then I have created another activity which is below which is Splash.java**

```
package com.example.timepass;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle tpsavedInstanceState)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(tpsavedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.splash);

Thread timer =new Thread()
{       
public void run()
{            
try
{

sleep(5000);
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{   {
e.printStackTrace();

}
finally
{
Intent openMainActivity =new Intent("com.example.timepass.MAINACTIVITY");
startActivity(openMainActivity);
}
 } 
};

timer.start(); 
}

}
```

**Then I have created Xml file related to Splash.java which is splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"     
android:background="@drawable/pic_background">
</LinearLayout>
```

**NOW I WANT TO RUN FIRST Splash.java file then MainActivity.java file so I have make some changes in Androidmanifest.xml file
here are the changes, and after running my program I get error "Unfortunately timepass has stopped" where timepass is my app name . please solve this issue**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.timepass"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<activity
android:name="com.example.timepass.Splash"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.example.timepass.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.example.timepass.MAINACTIVITY" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: post your logcat strings with errors

Comment: Look, I know you're new to Android development and that is why I am suggesting this to you: You can always see the cause of the crash in the Logcat that you have in Eclipse. Please learn how to go through it and you'll be facing far less problems thereafter. As of now, just post the Error Log and I'll help you out.

Answer (score 1):

//just do it like this

```
Intent openMainActivity =new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(openMainActivity);
```

instead of

```
Intent openMainActivity =new Intent("com.example.timepass.MAINACTIVITY");
startActivity(openMainActivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity in your manifest is used in two places. In one place it is in fully capital letter. Change that and give a try

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `{` before `e.printStackTrace();` in your Splash.java. Remove that and you'll be good to go.
Also post log for furthur errors in the future

Comment: I am just wondering how was he able to compile it with that error persisting; I'd expect Eclipse to throw an error straightaway!

Comment: I expected that too, but it's happened to me a couple of times when eclipse omitted errors from the log and compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your AndroidManifest.xml update your code after your application work properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.timepass"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<activity
android:name="com.example.timepass.Splash"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
android:name="com.example.timepass.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

change your code in splash.java

Intent i = new Intent(splash.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);